# Laravel 7 Route Resource and Jquery POST 301 issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-routing

I'm facing a very weird issue. I'm trying to store photo using Jquery AJAX.

My Route

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
```

My Blade Code

```
<form id="photo_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;">
       <input type="file" name="file" id="photo_file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"/>
       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" value="Upload and Get Link"/><br/>
</form>
```

My View AJAX Code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});


$("#photo_form").submit(function () {

        var formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('photo.index')}}",
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.status) {

                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.responseText);
            }
        });
});
```

My Controller Code

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        return [true];
}
```

when ajax call is called, it gives me 2 issue in network tab of firefox

```
POST https://fb.srdlict.com/photo
301 Moved Permanently
```

And

```
403 Forbidden
GET https://fb.srdlict.com/photo/
```

Seems like the ajax request is forwarded to `/photo/` route somehow and then `403` happened. Other routes are working fine. Just only this route. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are your routes using any middleware ? Are you using any validation/form request ? Show us your controller please.

Comment: Since you make Ajax requests instead of form submitting, I think you need to use apiResource routes.

Comment: @BülentAkgül that would not change anything related to the problem, but yeah, I agree with you.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I used only `auth` middleware. if that does is the case, then it will redirect to login instead of /photo/ index.

Comment: Are you using a token or session as auth ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti session. Its really strange. I worked with laravel for last 4 years and this stupid things happened. and still I cannot figure out why.

Comment: Are you using Auth API or Auth web ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti auth web